# Bootstrap 3 Calendar?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a calendar with bootstrap 3.3.7 
Something like this:

[image: It has to look something like this]
Important to me are the consistent square dates.

This is my attempt so far:
[image]

Getting close. But I don't like the code. It's not in Bootstrap and glitchy as crazy. I've tried ul/li lists. But I don't think that's the answer. Hope to do it in pure bootstrap code.

What is is I'm looking for:

- Square dates. So a responsive 1:1 height/width.
- amount of events on the date. Like a notification badge. Doesn't have to be in a circle/badge. Just in the top-right corner. I want to give the entire date that has events a colored background. So no need of a colored badge.
- Date/font size responsive to date cell. I don't know how to do this. My result had on small screens huge cells with mini font's :)
- Static html is fine.

I've tried it myself but 7 days in 12 columns is not nice.

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you have the code sample to go along with this as well?

Comment: The goal is to make a calendar out of bootstrap. But I don't know how to get 1. 7 columns out of 12 columns. 2. square cells. 3. the date horizontal/vertical centered. 4. a event badge in the top-right corner 
Yes/no. I have some code. But it is not in bootstrap. So I thought not to post it. Since it's messy and not in bootstrap, like my goal is. So I thought it might be miss communicating if I showed it.

Answer (score -1):

Why not using FullCalendar utility?

Fullcalendar is a jQuery calendar plugin.

Views can be customised to a certain extent, and there is also an API agains which to implement completely new view types for use within the rest of the calendar functionality.

Events can be dragged & dropped onto and around the calendar.

There is a wide range of callback functions and methods, so you can easily handle user actions, e.g select time/range, event resize/drag/drop etc.

You can download it for free from here:
https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Link-only answers are not allowed on SO

Comment: I am new here, thanks for your comments, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My goal would be to make it myself. The back-end is ready. Only have to make the front-end better.

Comment: FullCalendar includes css files, try to use them.